# How to get the preceding values in Redshift based on Where condition?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have three columns a student_name, column_1, column_2. I want to print the preceding value wherever the 0's exist in column 2.

I want the output like the below one, I used lag function. Probably I might be using it the wrong way.

[image]

Comment: "preceding" implies that there is an ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  There is no ordering. unless a column specifes the ordering.  Also, the logic for what you want to do is quite unclear.  Where do the numbers in the expected column come from?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want to count the number of `0` values up to and including each row.  If this interpretation is correct, you would use a conditional cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum( (column1 = 0)::int ) over (partition by student
                                       order by <ordering column>
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                      )
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have an ordering column which you have not included in the question.